# awk printf all text per line after first pattern including it

Tags: awk

Example operation:

Original text:

```
% echo -e "This is number 800 with decimal;other stuff\n44333; more data"
This is number 800 with decimal;other stuff
44333; more data
```

Desired awk result:

```
% echo -e "This is number 800 with decimal;other stuff\n44333; more data" | awk
;other stuff
; more data
```

UPDATE: after all answers: the separator ';' is only once per line and will exist if line exists, so my solution will always work, but it's not as universal as others solutions (which consider blank lines, lines with no separator o with more than one).

Comment: Why awk? `grep -o ';.*'` should work

Comment: @balki that would require a version of grep that supports the non-POSIX `-o` option whereas you can do it easily using any awk or any sed. It would also not print any line that did not have a `;` in it which may not be desired behavior (but the OP hasn't included that case in their example so idk).

Comment: You're getting answers that either won't print lines that don't contain `;` or will convert such lines to blank lines, or will print such lines as-is. You should [edit] your question to state how such lines should be handled.

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk or sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '{sub(/[^;]*/,"")}1' file

sed 's/[^;]*//' file
```

but the above would print blank lines for any line that doesn't contain `;` so if such lines can exist in your input then this may be what you want instead:

```
awk '{sub(/[^;]*;/,";")}1' file

sed 's/[^;]*;/;/' file
```

The above assumes you want any lines that do not contain `;`s to be printed as-is, or maybe you want such lines deleted:

```
awk 'sub(/[^;]*;/,";")' file

sed -n 's/[^;]*;/;/p' file
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcome. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { $1 = "" }; 1'
```

This reads each line's `;`-delimited fields and sets the first such field to the empty string.  All lines are then unconditionally outputted (that's what the lone `1` does at the end) with `;` as the output field delimiter.

Given the data in your question, this generates

```
;other stuff
; more data
```

Another test:

```bash
$ cat file
123;456;789
a b c ; d e f ; g h i

abba
;;;;
```

```bash
$ awk -F ';' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { $1 = ""; print }' file
;456;789
; d e f ; g h i


;;;;
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```c
echo -e "This is number 800 with decimal;other stuff\n44333; more data" |
awk 'match($0,/^[^;]*/){ print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}'

;other stuff
; more data
```

Answer (score -2):

Easy

```
% echo -e "This is number 800;other stuff\n44333; more data" | awk -F';' '{print ";"$2}'
;other stuff
; more data
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you asked for `awk printf all text per line after first pattern including it`, it prints the text between the first 2 `;`s, it wouldn't print the rest of the line if there were more `;`s. You also shouldn't hard-code the `;` multiple times and referencing a specific field forces awk to do field-splitting which may slow things down more than necessary.

Comment: This also inserts `;` on lines that were originally empty or only contained a single field.

Comment: @EdMorton you are both right.

Comment: @Kusalananda you are both right.